# String I/O in C with respect to MariaDB/MySQL C connector API?

Tags: mysql, c, database, string, mariadb

I am making a function in C using the MariaDB C-connector API, to allow users to enter a new username and password and have them stored in a MariaDB/MySQL database. I used strcpy_s() and strcat_s() to concatenate several strings together inside a buffer in order to produce the MariaDB/MySQL query to place the information into the database. This causes an 'unknown column in field list' error. I had asked a similar question on here before when I was implementing the function using "foo" and "bar" as preset strings, and the answer I received (which worked) was to change "foo" and "bar" to "'foo'" and "'bar'". This worked. Is there a way to have strings be taken from the user at run-time in the "'foo'" form versus the "foo" form? Below is the relevant code for the function.

```
void NEW_PLAYER(MYSQL *con)
{
    char NAME[16];
    char PASSWORD[16];
    char ch = NULL;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    printf("New Username: ");
    while (ch != '\n')    // terminates when the user presses enter
    {
        ch = getchar();
        NAME[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    NAME[i] = '\0';
    i = 0;
    ch = NULL;
    printf("New Password: ");
    while (ch != '\n')    // terminates if user hits enter
    {
        ch = getchar();
        PASSWORD[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    PASSWORD[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", NAME);
    printf("%s", PASSWORD);
    char TEMP[256];
    char str1[] = "INSERT INTO PLAYERS VALUES(";
    strcpy_s(TEMP, str1); strcat_s(TEMP, NAME); 
    strcat_s(TEMP, ", "); 
    strcat_s(TEMP, PASSWORD);
    strcat_s(TEMP, " ,0, 0, 0, 1)");

    if (mysql_query(con, TEMP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need quotes around literals in the `INSERT` statements.
- If `NAME`, `PASSWORD, and/or`TEMP` is not big enough, memory will be corrupted.
- You must to escape certain special characters (esp, quotes) in the NAME or PASSWORD.

`C` is a terribly low language to be playing with MySQL in.  In most languages that entire function, with the fixes, would take 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: Do you know any of Perl, PHP, VB, Java, Python?

Comment: Condolences.  I can understand using a particular language if that is all the team knows.  If it is because "C allows for better optimization", then that is false.  Sure, you can micro-optimize code better.  But the real performance gains are by looking at the big picture and optimizing the algorithm.  That is hard to do when so much of your time is spent with trivia such as string manipulation.  50 years ago, a similar mantra applied to "assembly language".

Comment: The connector is in C